# How to boot up react and node api server on same port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I built a simple express api server on `port 8080`. In another port(3000) i am building the client side with react which fetch data from my express api endpoint. For this i will have to run both of these applications on separate port. How can i run both of these in same port eg. 8080?
I am pretty new at this. help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1/ If you need them to run on the same port because of CORS issues, it may be easier (and good practice) to set up [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on your API server to allow requests from origin whatever:3000.

2/ To serve both the API and the static pages and scripts on the same port, you can either modify your API server to handle requests for the static content, or use a reverse proxy. I'd recommend [nginx to set that up](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) (and to serve the static content too, if you can).

Example nginx config:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

Comment: I got the cors issue covered and also static pages is not what i am looking to here. I am using react for the front end

Comment: I meant static from a server point of view. The React app is interpreted by the client. Unless you're doing server-side rendering? anyway, replace "static pages" with "front-end" if it makes more sense for you. You'll still want to use a reverse proxy to group both applications under the same origin.

Comment: Thanks that's actually an interesting idea replacing static ones with front-end. but so far i haven't seen any examples of it anywhere. Does it mean i set the `view engine` to `jsx`? could you kindly provide me with any examples or articles or videos?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I only meant that the words "front-end" instead of "static" may better reflect how you think of the React app, I wasn't thinking of changing your application. What I suggest (reverse proxying) is independent of how the applications work, you just have both apps running on different ports and then a proxy in front of them to dispatch requests to the correct app.

Comment: Oh i m sorry. I have seen something like this but did not quite understand that it said add a key `proxy` which value is the api server address. But could not get it quite.

Comment: I added a minimal example to show how the proxy would look like. If you want to try this and run into any issues, you should rather ask for help on ServerFault.